# Не работатет форма обратной связи php+sql

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Где я мог ошибиться? Вроде делал правельно, но данные не приходят в БД[image: php[![][![][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJB0w.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJB0w.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OCKf.png)

Comment: Ну для начала, опишите поведение вашего кода, редиректит ли вас на `index.html`, ну и как дополнение выведите хотя бы в блоке `catch`: `echo $e->getMessage()`, может что покажет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае, код не выполняется по двум причинам, `SQL-синтаксис` запроса `INSERT` не верен, по доке: `INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);`, а во вторых, в базе поля не `nullable`, и в таком формате запросы выполнять нельзя, в худшем случае, если бы в базе поля ж были `nullable`, то вы бы получили 4 записи, аля: `id: 0, name: Vasya, остальные поля null; id: 1, tel: 54643543, null, null; и тп.`, это можно обойти, если дополнительным запросом взять последний вставленный `id` и продолжить запросы уже с условием `WHERE id = $db->getLastInsertId()`.

---

```
 Решение: 

 $query = "INSERT INTO `feedback` (id, name, phone, email, product) VALUES (null, :name, :phone, :email, :product)";
 $msg = $conn->prepare($query);
 $msg->execute([
     'name'    => $_POST['name'],
     'phone'   => $_POST['tel'],
     'email'   => $_POST['email'],
     'product' => $_POST['product']
 ]);
```

---

Код не проверял, но смысл думаю ясен.